# Delete all files that do NOT start with something

Tags: bash

In Linux, how do I delete all files in a directory that do NOT start with a pref (for example sess_*)?

Answer (score 5):

Using Bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(sess_*)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to pipe it through grep.  For example:

```
cd /tmp ; ls -1 | grep -v sess_ | xargs rm -f
```

Another option is find (this excludes directories too):

```
find /tmp ! -name sess_\* ! -type d -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Why piping so much commands while 1 only can do the same job?

Comment: Why not?  If I didn't answer with it, I guarantee someone else would.  There's multiple ways to do things in UNIX.

Comment: Unnecessary use of resources (a pipe = a process + use of xargs ). You could use a shovel to hammer a nail but a hammer is much convenient don't you think?

Comment: I'd rather pipe three commands which are easy to understand and remember than having to memorize/consult parameters for the "find" command each time I want to do this.

Comment: @Benoit because `find` is old-fashioned, for example - just look at the way you have to give it the long command line options - witj a _single_ minus sign instead of  two !

Comment: @Ruan so would I ! find can do (almost) everything, but it's as complicated as a shovel would be that you can also use to slice the bread and stitch your shirt and drill a hole.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer find:

`find ./ -type f \( \! -name 'sess_*' \) -exec rm {} \;`

You might want to adjust depth in order to avoid recursion.

Answer (score 1):

In the above

cd /tmp ; ls -1 | grep -v sess_ | xargs rm -f

the grep should be grep -v '^sess_*'

Other wise files such as ppp_sess_333 would be left behind.